# I am trying to figure out the correct way to use microdata on a <figure> and <figcaption>

Tags: microdata

I tried this but keep getting errors saying that the address needs a value. However, this is exactly how they had it on schema.org

```
       <section class="content col-sm-4 mx-auto" id="germination" itemscope 
             itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"> 
           <a itemprop="url" 
             href="http://mevocals.weebly.com/germination.html">
        <img itemprop="image" class="img-fluid rounded " 
        src="https://freedomfieldme.net/images/germinationPoster_02.png" 
          alt="Germination poster of Freedom Field Cannabis Friendly camping 
        and music festival" title="Germination">
           <h4 itemprop="name">Germination Camping and Music Fesitval&#33; 
           </h4>
           </a>
           <p>Our first festival of the year. Come and help us start the 
              season off with a bang!</p>
           <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2018-04-17T1600">
            Thu, 04/17/2018<br>
            4:pm.
           <div itemprop="location" itemscope 
            itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">Freedom Field</div>
                <div itemprop="address" itemscope 
                   itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Harmony</span>
                    <span itemprop="addressRegion">ME</span>
                 </div>
            </section><!--germination-->
```

Comment: did you try something  are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I changed the code to mimic shema.org's example. However I keep getting errors about address not having a value

Comment: Where do you get the error? Please [edit] your question and quote the error message.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the many responses. All one of you.